# Hola amigos, necesito ayuda con un programa que estoy haciendo con Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

Me gustaría que después del elif, el usuario pueda volver al print inicial de una forma sencilla, ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?, Gracias de antemano.

```
name = str(input('Escribe tu nombre para comenzar: '))

print('\nHola {} bienvenido a este juego de trivia, escribe alguno de los siguientes comandos para empezar: \n -"Jugar" para empezar la trivia \n -"Instrucciones" para saber cómo se juega '.format(name))

comands_1 = str(input('= ')).lower()

if comands_1 == 'jugar':
    print(str('\n Muy bien {}, ahora elige que trivia deseas realizar: \n -Disney \n -Programación \n -Animales'.format(name)))

elif comands_1 == 'instrucciones':
    print(str('Este juego de trivia consiste en una serie de pregunatas de un tema especifico, en el cual debes responder escribiendo la letra de la opción que consideres correcta'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más rápido y sencillo que se me ocurre sin modificar mucho tu código es estructurarlo por funciones. Una función `main` que ejecuta el input y el print del nombre del usuario y otro `game` que gestiona el juego.

```py
def main():
    name = str(input('Escribe tu nombre para comenzar: '))
    print('\nHola {} bienvenido a este juego de trivia, escribe alguno de los siguientes comandos para empezar: \n -"Jugar" para empezar la trivia \n -"Instrucciones" para saber cómo se juega \n -"Volver" para volver a empezar'.format(name))
    game(name)

def game(name:str):
    comands_1 = str(input('= ')).lower()

    if comands_1 == 'jugar':
        print(str('\n Muy bien {}, ahora elige que trivia deseas realizar: \n -Disney \n -Programación \n -Animales'.format(name)))
    elif comands_1 == 'instrucciones':
        print(str('Este juego de trivia consiste en una serie de pregunatas de un tema especifico, en el cual debes responder escribiendo la letra de la opción que consideres correcta'))
    elif comands_1 == 'volver':
        main()

main()
```

No se si es exactamente lo que quieres, pero podría ser una solución volver a llamar a la función `main()` que vuelve a capturar el nombre del jugador y empieza todo el juego. Para ello añadí un nuevo elif que es 'volver'.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, aunque no era así exactamente me ayudaste a arreglarlo como lo necesitaba gracias